# Semi-sort a column containing semi colon separated values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

Using SQL Server 2019.

I am trying to semi sort the column **empDates** in the table *#employeeData* where all the NULLs are at the "front" or "end" and the dates are in chronological order

```
CREATE TABLE #employeeData(
    empName VARCHAR(50)
    , empDates NVARCHAR(MAX)
);

INSERT INTO #employeeData(empName, empDates)
VALUES
('John Smith', 'NULL;2010-04-13;2007-10-05')
, ('Joe Jones', 'NULL;2014-03-28;2012-07-05')
, ('Henry Lakes' , '2034-11-14;2038-07-01;2034-11-14;2030-02-26')
, ('Harry Public', '2019-09-15;2021-07-04;NULL;NULL;2019-09-15');
```

Below is what I have tried and where I am stuck.
I do not know how to "unzip" sort "re-zip" all in the same column cell

```
select spA.value
from #employeeDate
cross apply string_split(empDates, ';') as spA
```

Below is the desired table for the given information

| empName | empDates |
| --- | --- |
| 'John Smith' | 'NULL;2007-10-05;2010-04-13' |
| 'Joe Jones' | 'NULL;2012-07-05;2014-03-28' |
| 'Henry Lakes' | '2030-02-26;2034-11-14;2034-11-14;2038-07-01' |
| 'Harry Public' | 'NULL;NULL;2019-09-15;2019-09-15;2021-07-04' |

Comment: The real issue here: don't store denormalized data in the first place. These dates should be in a separate table.

Answer (score 2):

The inverse of `string_split` is `string_agg`, so

```
with q as
(
  select  empName, spA.value d
  from    #employeeData cross apply string_split(empDates, ';') as spA 
)
select empName, STRING_AGG(d,';') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY case when d = 'NULL' then null else d end )   empDates
from q
group by empName
```

outputs

```
empName                                            empDates
-------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------
Harry Public                                       NULL;NULL;2019-09-15;2019-09-15;2021-07-04
Henry Lakes                                        2030-02-26;2034-11-14;2034-11-14;2038-07-01
Joe Jones                                          NULL;2012-07-05;2014-03-28
John Smith                                         NULL;2007-10-05;2010-04-13

(4 rows affected)
```

Comment: Seems like it might be more efficient to do the whole thing in a subquery per row `SELECT empName, (SELECT STRING_AGG(d,';') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY case when d = 'NULL' then null else d end ) FROM string_split(empDates, ';') as spA) FROM #employeeData` no grouping necessary.

Comment: I was looking at the same a @Charlieface, but with `ORDER BY TRY_CONVERT(DATE, S.value)`. Or perhaps `ORDER BY NULLIF(S.value, 'NULL')` .

Comment: That’s a direct and elegant solution. My intuition is to first normalize the data into a proper table and then figure out the next steps.